# How to Filter and Sort array of object within array of object in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql

Hi I have my payload like below:

```
{
  "Id": "3",
  "List": {
    "Steps": [
      {
        "StepId": "1",
        "stepDesc1": [
          {
            "sortNo": "2",
            "description": "ABC"
          },
          {
            "sortNo": "1",
            "description": "XYZ"
          }
        ],
        "stepDesc2": [
          {
            "sortNo": "2",
            "description": "AAA"
          },
          {
            "sortNo": "1",
            "description": "BBB"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "StepId": "2",
        "stepDesc1": [
          {
            "sortNo": "2",
            "description": "CCC"
          },
          {
            "sortNo": "1",
            "description": "DDD"
          }
        ],
        "stepDesc2": [
          {
            "sortNo": "2",
            "description": "EEE"
          },
          {
            "sortNo": "1",
            "description": "FFF"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to FILTER by Id and StepId and sort by SortNo and return data

I have used below query to filter by Id and StepId

```
FOR test IN test_data
FILTER test.Id=='3' 
FILTER '1' IN test.List.Steps[*].StepId
SORT test.List.Steps[*].stepDesc1.sortNo ASC
RETURN test.Steps
```

but Second filter condition is not working and returning me all Steps corresponding to the Id 3. In my case it should return below o/p

```
{
        "StepId": "1",
        "stepDesc1": [
          {
            "sortNo": "2",
            "description": "ABC"
          },
          {
            "sortNo": "1",
            "description": "XYZ"
          }
        ],
        "stepDesc2": [
          {
            "sortNo": "2",
            "description": "AAA"
          },
          {
            "sortNo": "1",
            "description": "BBB"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Can any one help me with a solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this.  Because the second FILTER you are apply is true `1` is indeed in the array, but that AQL isn't excluding `2`.  It is only saying `1` must be present.  If you loop the nested array - then you can use the `==`.  Hope this helps.

```
FOR test IN test_data
   FILTER test.Id == '3' 
    FOR step IN test.List.Steps
        FILTER step.StepId == '1' 
        SORT step[*].stepDesc1.sortNo ASC

RETURN step
```